# What exactly is a client?

Tags: terminology

In the context of the Internet I always thought of a client being something or someone requesting something from a server (Server-Client model).

Then I stumbled upon Git and it's numerous clients. The one I chose first was the TortoiseGit client.

But what makes TortoiseGit a client? It doesn't communicate with a server (I only use Git locally) and the only thing it really communicates to is git.exe I guess, would git.exe be the "server" then and TortoiseGit the "client"?

Or does the term client have multiple meanings and the meaning in the context of Git GUI is a different when talking about the Internet?

Answer (score 2):

> But what makes TortoiseGit a client? It doesn't communicate with a server (I only use Git locally) and the only thing it really communicates to is git.exe I guess, would git.exe be the "server" then and TortoiseGit the "client"?

One reason for this description is that TortoiseGit comes from TortoiseSVN, and in SVN there is no local repository – the local svn.exe tool cannot do a lot without talking to the server, so it's naturally a "SVN client", and while TortoiseGit can be more self-sufficient the terminology has stuck.

But from the user's perspective, TortoiseGit is in the *same* category as git.exe in that it communicates with Git remote repositories, so it's a "Git client" in the same way as git.exe is. The fact that it relies on an external git.exe command to do so is immaterial – it's just an "under the hood" implementation detail and doesn't affect the overall purpose of the program.

(In the same way, git.exe itself is described as a Git client even though it relies on ssh.exe or plink.exe to make SSH connections to a remote Git SSH server.)